# ValueError when running MaskedAutoregressiveFlow example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run the example for MaskedAutoregressiveFlow at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/bijectors/MaskedAutoregressiveFlow. It's a plain copy from the docs but I receive the following error. I've tried `event_shape=[dims, 1]` but that doesn't seem to help (different error). I'm not sure what to make of it.

Has anyone seen this as well?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as tfd

from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import bijectors as tfb

dims = 5

# A common choice for a normalizing flow is to use a Gaussian for the base
# distribution. (However, any continuous distribution would work.) E.g.,
maf = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    distribution=tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.),
    bijector=tfb.MaskedAutoregressiveFlow(
        shift_and_log_scale_fn=tfb.masked_autoregressive_default_template(
            hidden_layers=[512, 512])),
    event_shape=[dims])


x = maf.sample()  # Expensive; uses `tf.while_loop`, no Bijector caching.
maf.log_prob(x)   # Almost free; uses Bijector caching.
maf.log_prob(0.)  # Cheap; no `tf.while_loop` despite no Bijector caching.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3b2fcb2af309> in <module>()
     11 
     12 
---> 13 x = maf.sample()  # Expensive; uses `tf.while_loop`, no Bijector caching.
     14 maf.log_prob(x)   # Almost free; uses Bijector caching.
     15 maf.log_prob(0.)  # Cheap; no `tf.while_loop` despite no Bijector caching.

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/distribution.py in sample(self, sample_shape, seed, name)
        687       samples: a `Tensor` with prepended dimensions `sample_shape`.
        688     """
    --> 689     return self._call_sample_n(sample_shape, seed, name)
        690 
        691   def _log_prob(self, value):

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/transformed_distribution.py in _call_sample_n(self, sample_shape, seed, name, **kwargs)
        411       # work, it is imperative that this is the last modification to the
        412       # returned result.
    --> 413       y = self.bijector.forward(x, **kwargs)
        414       y = self._set_sample_static_shape(y, sample_shape)
        415 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/bijector_impl.py in forward(self, x, name)
        618       NotImplementedError: if `_forward` is not implemented.
        619     """
    --> 620     return self._call_forward(x, name)
        621 
        622   def _inverse(self, y):

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/bijector_impl.py in _call_forward(self, x, name, **kwargs)
        599       if mapping.y is not None:
        600         return mapping.y
    --> 601       mapping = mapping.merge(y=self._forward(x, **kwargs))
        602       self._cache(mapping)
        603       return mapping.y

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/bijectors/masked_autoregressive.py in _forward(self, x)
        245     y0 = array_ops.zeros_like(x, name="y0")
        246     # call the template once to ensure creation
    --> 247     _ = self._shift_and_log_scale_fn(y0)
        248     def _loop_body(index, y0):
        249       """While-loop body for autoregression calculation."""

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/template.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        358           custom_getter=self._custom_getter) as vs:
        359         self._variable_scope = vs
    --> 360         result = self._call_func(args, kwargs)
        361         return result
        362 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/template.py in _call_func(self, args, kwargs)
        300       trainable_at_start = len(
        301           ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))
    --> 302       result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
        303 
        304       if self._variables_created:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/bijectors/masked_autoregressive.py in _fn(x)
        478             activation=activation,
        479             *args,
    --> 480             **kwargs)
        481       x = masked_dense(
        482           inputs=x,

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/bijectors/masked_autoregressive.py in masked_dense(inputs, units, num_blocks, exclusive, kernel_initializer, reuse, name, *args, **kwargs)
        386         *args,
        387         **kwargs)
    --> 388     return layer.apply(inputs)
        389 
        390 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in apply(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        807       Output tensor(s).
        808     """
    --> 809     return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        810 
        811   def _add_inbound_node(self,

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        671 
        672           # Check input assumptions set before layer building, e.g. input rank.
    --> 673           self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
        674           if input_list and self._dtype is None:
        675             try:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in _assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
       1195                            ', found ndim=' + str(ndim) +
       1196                            '. Full shape received: ' +
    -> 1197                            str(x.get_shape().as_list()))
       1198       # Check dtype.
       1199       if spec.dtype is not None:

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [5]

    originally defined at:
      File "<ipython-input-2-3b2fcb2af309>", line 9, in <module>
        hidden_layers=[512, 512])),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/bijectors/masked_autoregressive.py", line 499, in masked_autoregressive_default_template
        "masked_autoregressive_default_template", _fn)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/template.py", line 152, in make_template
        **kwargs)
```